# Is it a good practice to use Java Streams in POJO as attributes

Tags: java, list, collections, java-stream

I just saw this for the first time and I would like to know if this is a good practice or as always it depends.

Using Streams as attributes in the domain instead of a List.

```
public class MyDomain {

    Integer id;
    Stream<SubDomain> subDomains;

}
```

Comment: Nope, it's not a good idea as long as each Stream is made for only for the one-time processing and not the actual data storage.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, that isn't a good practice. Streams have been created to support functional-style operations on streams of elements (see [official Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)) but not to persist them.

The is an other good quote in the official Javadoc:

> Streams differ from collections in several ways:
> No storage. A stream is not a data structure that stores elements; instead, it conveys elements from a source such as a data structure, an array, a generator function, or an I/O channel, through a pipeline of computational operations.

So don't use it as a persistent collection.

Answer (score 8):

This is not a good idea, a stream can be consumed once. Having it as a field in an object will make it likely it is necessary to consume more than once. To be able to do that, you need to store the collection class (eg a `List`), and call its `stream()` method when you need to access its contents as a stream.